# Disable File Editing function

Tags: css, html, editor, code

Researching fixing errors while validating my site, I got brave and clicked Enable button at Appearance > Editor and went pass the "warning" - now getting nervous bc don't want to accidentally mess something up, I would like to reverse that decision and "Disable" that option so that i don't access that section right now. Can i just flip a button to return to the page showing Enable file editing without touching the code?
Thanks...
(ps... I'll have to keep looking for the better way to fix the errors showing up on the validator.)

Answer (score 2):

There is no "Enable" button I'm aware of, but if you want to fully disable file editing, then that's easy.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Hardening_WordPress#Disable_File_Editing

Add this line to your wp-config.php file:

`define('DISALLOW_FILE_EDIT', true);`

No more file editing in WordPress.

Comment: I'll look for that file in the editor and c/p it. Does it matter where in the file it should appear?

Comment: I'll look for that file in the editor and c/p it. Does it matter where in the wp-config.php file it should appear? And does this reset the button so the Enable reappears in Appearance > Editor?

Comment: the link you sent says:  Append the following two lines to the end of your wp-config file:

## Disable Editing in Dashboard
define('DISALLOW_FILE_EDIT', true);

so both?

Comment: It should be at the top of the file, in with all the other defines. The wp-config consists of defines followed by a require at the end. This is what the wp-config file is for, to define all the constants, and then to include the main WP file to load all the rest of the system. The order of the defines is basically irrelevant, organize as you please. The important thing is the last line being last. The rest mostly doesn't matter.